# Why does the "combat triangle" work?

Tags: medieval, balancing-magic-systems

In the medieval MMORPG Runescape, the combat is balanced by a concept called the [combat trinagle](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Combat_triangle).
Basically it's like rock-paper-scissors: melee is effective against range, range is effective against magic and magic is effective against melee.

[image: Combat triangle]
[image]

I understand that in the game this is for balancing purposes, however worldbuilding wise it does not make sense to me.
Melee weapons would be better at cutting through cloth wizard's robes than against tougher ranger's armor.
Magical attacks would also be at least as good against the weaker rangers armor as against the chain or plate of the warrior.

So, why does the combat triangle work the way it does?

Comment: Seems like you have already answered your own question ("*this is for balancing purposes*"). More realistic and detailed rules degrade playability and make the game less fun to play. Ask anybody who has plodded through three days of a single Star Fleet Battles engagement, filling out Energy Allocation Forms over and over.

Comment: It looks like you're asking a question about game design rather than building a specific fictional world. Such questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: If you were making your own game and asking how to balance the powers in that, then it might work as a question. (Remember the [edit] button for later).

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane Game balance is separate from worldbuilding. Perhaps if they're looking for an in world explanation for their game mechanics, but then they'd need to explicitly describe the game mechanics, in their game, and enough information about their world for us to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

Mages use magic. Unfortunately, magic power decreases at range. In physics, inverse-square relationships show up all the time, so this wouldn't be unusual. This means:

**Mages are strong against warriors and weak against ranged fighters** because at close range is where their magic works best. Roasting someone with a burst of flame who's only a couple meters away is much, *much* easier than projecting a flame several hundred meters away to an archer.

Now, on to the next category: Melee fighters. These guys use heavy armor along with weapons like swords or polearms and maybe a shield in the off-hand.

**Melee fighters are strong against ranged units and weak against mages** because their heavy armor and shields make it easy to deflect or tank the purely physical attacks from a ranged fighter, by, for example, catching arrows in their shield. Against mages though, this armor isn't as effective because the mage can still telekinetically rip you limb from limb or roast you regardless how thick your plate is.

Finally, we have the ranged category. They use bows and other ranged weaponry like crossbows to perform physical attacks at long ranges. This means that:

**Ranged fighters are strong against mages and weak against melee fighters** because they can attack lightly-armored mages at range which, because magic works poorly at range, means that they have the advantage. Against melee fighters they struggle though, because the purely physical defenses of shields and armor make it possible for the melee fighters to close the gap and engage the archers with their swords and spears.

**Now, some "plot-holes":**

Q: Why don't mages just wear heavy armor and use shields then?

A: Mages can't wear armor because the metal obstructs their magic somehow. This is why they are lightly armored, and only wear non-metallic armors like enchanted cloth or leather.

Q: Why don't ranged fighters wear heavy armor to better defend against melee fighters?

A: The archery strategy involves a lot of rapid-repositioning on the battlefield to get optimum angles, and to escape from melee fighters. Thick armor would hinder mobility.

Answer (score 1):

**Just range and effectiveness of armor.**

Warriors have range 1, wizards range 2, archers range 3.

Wizard attack is indifferent to armor.  Archer attack blocked by armor.  Warrior attack slowed by armor.

Warrior would waste wizard but warrior cannot get close enough.  Wizard attack does not care about armor.

Warrior does waste archer because he can get close enough.  Warrior armor good vs archer attack and warrior moves fast.

Archer can hit unarmored wizard from out past wizard range.  Wizard has no armor and under robes has on only gold lamee Speedo and piercings.  Wizard also wears wildly impractical shoes and so cannot run and close the distance.

Answer (score 1):

**Metal is conductive to magic**

A mage can thereby only hurt someone wearing armor. So having armor makes you vulnerable to magic but also protected against arrows. The mage can also push away larger nearby objects making a warrior useless as a mage counter. A archer on the other hand have no armor to conduct magic and their arrows move to fast to be deflected.

The warrior have an advantage over a archer, their thick armor defect any arrows shot their way.
Under these circumstances it makes no sense to not specialize.
A archer with armor have trouble shooting, is vulerable to magic and loose to a warrior in close combat.
A warrior without armor is pushed away when close to a mage and is vulnerable to arrows. Armor on a mage makes his own spells self inflicting.

So its better to bet on being good against one of these types. Armies have all three types mixed in their ranks, being ready to deploy the best counter. On the battlefield leaders try to outmanuvre eachother by faking a mage charge to lure out the enemy archer and then revealing their warriors.

Answer (score -2):

**It's about who makes the first move.**

A dude with armor and a swingy weapon beats a dude with clothes and a bow and arrows, provided they fight at melee range. The swingy weapon is designed to be used close up but the bow is not.

A dude with clothes and a bow and arrows beats a dude with a spellbook and magic staff, provided he sneaks up on the wizard and shoots him, before the wizard has a chance to cast any spells. He is good at sneaking because of his light armor.

A wizard with a spellbook and magic staff beats a dude with armor and a swingy weapon, provided he sees him coming and has time to cast a spell. It is easy to see or hear the armored dude coming cause his armor goes clank clank clank.

Comment: You are answering "who wins among a wizard, a bowman and a clubman?" which is not OP's question

Comment: See: [Caucus race](https://aliceinwonderland.fandom.com/wiki/Caucus_Race) from Lewis Carrol.